# Нужно вывести json определенной структуры

Tags: c#, json

гуру, сенсеи, мастера, наставники и все причастные!
Прошу помощи.
Поставили задачу сделать вывод json следующей структуры:

```
{
 Дата  
 Номер дома:  
 {  
   квартира1:  
        {  
         Проживающий1  
         Проживающий2 ..  
        }  
   квартира2:  
        {  
         Проживающий1  
         Проживающий2 ..  
        }  
     }  
   }
```

у меня получается сделать только вывод "квартира1", а как сделать такой сложной структуры - не пойму.

```
    app.Run(async (context) => 
    {
     Appart appart1 = new Appart("Иванов", "Иванова");
     string fileName="living.json"; 
    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(appart1);
     File.WriteAllText(filename, jsonString);
     await context.Response.SendFileAsync(living.json);
     } )
app.Run();

 public class Appart
{
     public string Living1 {get; set;}
     public string Living2 {get; set;}
 public Appart(string living1, string living2)
 {
 Living1 = living1;
 Living2 = living2;
 } 
}
```

Как мне кажется должен быть создан "общий" объект, содержащий в себе дату, объект "Номер дома", в свою очередь, объект "номер дома", должен содержать объекты "квартира N", которые содержат в себе "Проживающий N". Собственно вот эту структуру я и не могу реализовать. Вероятно, что я заблуждаюсь в своем представлении структуры.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, для начала

Comment: Выводится все  в браузер. В студии использую web-app.
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
Appart appart1 = new Appart("Иванов", "Иванова");
string fileName="living.json";
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(appart1);
File.WriteAllText(filename, jsonString);
await context.Response.SendFileAsync(living.json);
}
)

public class Appart
{
public string Living1 {get; set;}
public string Living2 {get; set;}
public Appart(string living1, string living2)
{
Living1 = living1;
Living2 = living2;
}
}

Сразу прошу прощения за форматирование. Не освоился здесь еще.

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Редактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Поправил

Comment: `public class Root { public DateTime Date  {get;} public Apartment[] Apartments {get;} }` далее сам класс "квартиры" `public class Apartment { public Resident Resident {get;} }`, ну и класс проживающего сделаете по аналогии сами. Тут как видите все просто `{ ... }` - это класс, `[...]` - это массив/коллекция, `"...": ...` - это свойство, с именем и неким значением, если название свойства динамично, то это словарь. Вот собственно и комбинируйте это все как надо.

Comment: Спасибо. В целом - решение подходящее, но у меня появился еще один вопрос. Можно ли такую структуру реализовать не используя массив, т.к. при формировании json получается конструкция { [ ... ] }, а мне хотелось бы получить именно так, как указано в примере

Comment: Нагуглился и получил необходимый вариант. Решается через Dictoinary<>. Всем спасибо. Можно закрывать, а @EvgeniyZ плюиск в карму!